# Do answers become community wiki too easily?

Tags: discussion

This is a situation I find quite frustrating, which seems to be happening to me a lot lately.

I will answer a question. After pondering it, I may think of some additional points.

Later I will go back and fix some typos.

Then the OP will post some or all of his or her data. I will add some displays or other analysis, or maybe just post some comments based on some analysis of their data.

Then the OP may make a number of comments on my answer, with followup questions. Other people add more questions.

Responding to those sometimes requires many changes to my answer (even if I'd like to respond in comments, often my answers are quite extensive and involve research - finding papers, doing simulations and so on). The responses are often much too long for a comment.

As a result, to produce a good responsive answer tends to take a large number of edits over a couple of days, sometimes several edits in quick succession (respond to OP, respond to other people, notice one or more responses to my responses requiring further edits).

At least three times recently I've seen good answers I've invested many hours in polishing turn community wiki, *when they really aren't community wiki* - I've just been making a better, more responsive answer in multiple stages.

It's a major turn off to fixing mistakes, to putting in illustrative graphics when the data becomes available, to finding more relevant research and to responding to followup questions. That is, it puts me off giving better answers, when that time could be invested elsewhere.

But I also don't want to be bothering moderators to say 'please unwiki this' several times a week.

Is it possible to turn down - even just a little - how sensitive CV is to edits to answers from one person?

Is this something worth pursuing? Is it something that's not likely to be easily done?

Should I just be producing less ambitious, less responsive answers?

---

**Edit**: Comment/update added 1 May 2014 (local time)

I think the recent changes to the way automatic CWing works pretty much deals with my concerns on this issue.

Comment: The editing facilities can be abused, which is the reason this is in place (by my understanding). After 10 edits by the first author, the post is automatically converted to CW. Other than flagging and requesting that the CW status be reverted, [here is an alternative approach](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4666/7003) if you think your edits are going to be copious and spread out over many sessions.

Comment: It's little trouble to respond to flags to "please unwiki this"--it doesn't take any thought and shouldn't be considered bothering the moderators.  I think I can speak for all moderators everywhere when I say we appreciate efforts like yours to enhance and improve answers.

Comment: To answer the question posed in the title (and not all of the subsequent ones, which is why I'm only posting a comment) - my opinion is **Yes**. If each of the edits are constructive and are not obvious gimmicks to bump the question, then I see no value in having an automatic cap on the number of edits allowed before you stop earning reputation. If there is clear "nuisance" editing occurring, it should be flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to this; I certainly appreciate people's having put some time and effort into making answers on CV great. That is what will make CV a valuable resource. I didn't know it was possible to 'unwiki' an answer, but I vote that it should be done when answers were edited constructively. I will say that I find this a bit curious, though. I've put some effort into several of my answers, & I don't think I've ever had an answer made CW except by me or b/c the thread is.

Comment: @gung It takes quite a lot of edits. I've worked on making as few edits as I can, but on some questions, over a couple of days I still seem to be hitting it.

Comment: By the way, this automatic conversion has never happened to me, but in several instances (on this site and others) I've flagged the answers of other users that have had their posts converted and have asked that the CW be removed. The moderators have always obliged (quickly).

Comment: @cardinal I've never had anything but speedy responses from moderators on any issue. That is not among my worries, at least. Thanks for all your useful pointers and comments.

Comment: I was going to write a meta question about this, then found this thread. Is it still a good practice to flag answers that seem to be regular answers but have been made community wiki by their authors? I just came across another example and flagged it; but have wondered about this before. It doesn't happen very often.

Comment: Much more rarely now than was once the case. I don't think it's happened to me in ages, and I take less care than I did at the time of this post to try to avoid small edits. This question may be effectively outdated by the changes to the way the site works.

Comment: Yes, the flag was declined. I just realized how to look up the moderator's feedback to the flags I raise. Here is the response about that particular flag: "The OP chose to make it CW, which is always an option." Will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To close the loop:

> But I also don't want to be bothering moderators to say 'please unwiki this' several times a week.

As per one of the moderators (**whuber**, above, in comments):

> It's little trouble to respond to flags to "please unwiki this"--it doesn't take any thought and shouldn't be considered bothering the moderators. I think I can speak for all moderators everywhere when I say we appreciate efforts like yours to enhance and improve answers.

So please: continue to flag for un-wiki-ing!

> Is it possible to turn down - even just a little - how sensitive CV is to edits to answers from one person?

Please note that yours is something of an....unusual case. Most people don't edit their answers 20+ times. There's nothing wrong with this! And it appears your behavior is 100% in line with things we *like* to see. As aforementioned: please simply flag your wiki'ed answers to have that removed.

> Should I just be producing less ambitious, less responsive answers?

***NEVER!***

Comment: (+1 -- why the -1?!) I'll second @whuber's comment about CW flags: they do not bother me, and I always appreciate users concerned with the quality of their answers, and those who clearly demonstrate they are attentive to others' requests.

Comment: here is a [the answer to the question "Is there a way to remove community wiki status?" on meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373)